# I can't see any menu in my new installed VS2012 on Win7 x64

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just get a very strange issue about my new installed VS 2012.
As you see in the screen shots it was OK to see the menu under 'File' option in my VS 2010 but at the same place of VS 2012 I couldn't see the popup menu after click the 'File' option.

However, I could trigger the function in the menu by shortcut keys such as 'X' to exit and double 'Enter' to create a new project.

Besides this I also can't see any the context menu in the IDE by pressing right mouse button.

I have tried to re-install VS 2010 and 2012 times and times but the issue is never fixed.

Do you have any idea about this? Thanks.

[image: VS 2010]

[image: VS 2012]

Comment: really spooky. Mail the print screens to Microsoft

Comment: Can you update your video drivers?  Can you turn off Hardware Acceleration in the Visual Studio options?

Comment: I just updated to the latest video drivers. As you could see as the menu is invisible how could I open the Options...

Comment: Well, I made to. By pressing 'O' key blindly after click 'TOOLS' I have unchecked the Hardware Acceleration and everything returns to OK. Thanks.